# zxing onActivityResult not called in Fragment only in Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, zxing, onactivityresult

I'm having some issue with zxing  onActivityResult().

As you can see in the code I did properly invoke new intent as described in https://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent.

The question is how can I catch onActivityResult() in Fragment, since I need this data in my Fragmnet and not in Activity?

```
package com.example.testingcodereading;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

private Button mButtonXZing;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle     savedInstanceState){
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, parent, false);

    mButtonXZing = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button_xzing);
    mButtonXZing.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(getActivity());
            integrator.initiateScan();

        }
    });

    return v;
}


@Override 
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    System.out.println("never here");
      IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
      if (scanResult != null) {
        // handle scan result
      }
      // else continue with any other code you need in the method
    }

}
```

---

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
Fragment f = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);

if(f == null){
  f = new MainFragment();
  fm.beginTransaction()
    .add(R.id.fragmentContainer, f)
    .commit();
}
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    System.out.println("the code is catch");
}

}
```

Comment: Use `Integrator.forSupportFragment(this)` or `Integrator.forFragment(this)` depending on which `Fragment` you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If any one have the same issue here is my solution.

```
package com.example.testingcodereading;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment);

FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
Fragment f = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);

if (f == null) {
  f = MainFragment.newInstance("Start Application");
  fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentContainer, f).commit();
}
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
  Intent intent) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
System.out.println("the code is catch");

IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(
    requestCode, resultCode, intent);
// handle scan result
if (scanResult != null) {
  FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

  Fragment newFrame = MainFragment.newInstance(scanResult.toString());

  fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, newFrame).commit();
}

}

}
```

---

```
package com.example.testingcodereading;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.test.suitebuilder.annotation.MediumTest;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String EXTRA_CODE = "com.example.testingcodereading.code";
private Button mButtonXZing;
private TextView mTextView;


public static MainFragment newInstance(String code) {
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putSerializable(EXTRA_CODE, code);

MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
fragment.setArguments(args);

return fragment;
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle    savedInstanceState){
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, parent, false);

mTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text_code);
mTextView.setText((String) getArguments().getSerializable(EXTRA_CODE));

mButtonXZing = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button_xzing);
mButtonXZing.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {

    IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(getActivity());
    integrator.initiateScan();
  }
});

return v;
}


@Override 
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
System.out.println("never here");
IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
if (scanResult != null) {
  // handle scan result
}
// else continue with any other code you need in the method
}

}
```

Comment: Good enough. One thing to watch for is the context since the context used by a fragment is inherited from the parent Activity hosting the fragment then once the fragment is instantiated, it takes on this context and works in it's own space.

Comment: Get more about manipulating fragments and how they actually work from Google's documentation (http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Comment: Why you did not use previous anser. It's more elegant desision)

Answer (score 36):

As `Martynnw` pointed out the issue is to call `fragment.startActivityForResult` instead of `activity.startActivityForResult`. So just use next wrapper:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator;

public final class FragmentIntentIntegrator extends IntentIntegrator {

    private final Fragment fragment;

    public FragmentIntentIntegrator(Fragment fragment) {
        super(fragment.getActivity());
        this.fragment = fragment;
    }

    @Override
    protected void startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int code) {
        fragment.startActivityForResult(intent, code);
    }
}
```

Comment: But how do you use this class?

Comment: @PhilippLudwig just replace IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(MyActivity.this); with FragmentIntentIntegrator integrator = new FragmentIntentIntegrator(MyFragment.this);

Comment: Use `Integrator.forSupportFragment(this)` or `Integrator.forFragment(this)` depending on which `Fragment` you are using.

Answer (score 14):

```
integrator.initiateScan();
```

Change the above line as

```
integrator.forSupportFragment(fragment_name.this).initiateScan();
```

Comment: I've tried using this in a fragment. It's able to display the QR camera, however, onActivityResult is not called when a code is scanned

Comment: @user1872384 I had the same problem until I realized that the scanner was starting in landscape mode and I was rotating the phone which was restarting the activity.  It works for me if you don't rotate the phone.  I ended up setting the camera in portrait mode to avoid that.

Answer (score 4):

Alternative **ZXing Android Embedded**, implementation:

```
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator;
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentResult;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    new IntentIntegrator(this).initiateScan(); // `this` is the current Activity

}
```

Use from a Fragment:

```
IntentIntegrator.forFragment(this).initiateScan(); // `this` is the current Fragment

// If you're using the support library, use: 
// IntentIntegrator.forSupportFragment(this) instead.
```

Get the results:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,Intent data) {
    IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(result != null) {
        if(result.getContents() == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Scanned: " + result.getContents(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

[more info and options](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded)

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem and resolved it with below codes:

```
IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(getActivity());                
integrator.forSupportFragment(MyFragment.this).initiateScan();
```

Answer (score 2):

Shall call the scan in this way:

```
IntentIntegrator.forSupportFragment(YourFragment.this)
                    .setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE)
                    .setBeepEnabled(true/false)
                    .setPrompt("blahblahblah")
                    .initiateScan();
```

Then you can get the scan result in Fragment's onActivityResult

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `OnActivityResult` in your `Activity` is calling `super.OnActivityResult()`. That should ensure it's called on the `Fragment` as well.

Alternatively, you could modify the `IntentIntegrator` code so it calls `StartActivityResult` on the `Fragment`, either by passing the fragment to the constructor, or passing it to `initiateScan`.

Comment: Well I did solve the problem, by replacing the fragment. Here is the solution: http://androide-examples.blogspot.com/2013/11/zxing-onactivityresult-called-only-in.html

Answer (score 1):

Try creating `IntentIntegrator` object in `Fragment` as below.

```
        val scanIntegrator = IntentIntegrator.forSupportFragment(this@HomeFragment)
        scanIntegrator.setPrompt("Scan")
        scanIntegrator.setBeepEnabled(true)
        //The following line if you want QR code
        scanIntegrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE_TYPES)
        scanIntegrator.captureActivity = CaptureActivityAnyOrientation::class.java
        scanIntegrator.setOrientationLocked(true)
        scanIntegrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(true)
        scanIntegrator.initiateScan()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public void scanCode() {
        IntentIntegrator.forSupportFragment(this).
        setCaptureActivity(CaptureAct.class).
        setOrientationLocked(false)
        .setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.PRODUCT_CODE_TYPES)
        .setPrompt("Scanning code")
        .initiateScan();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution : A basic example of how you can manage it

Main Activity

```
public static int tapTrick = 0;

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    //super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(tapTrick!=0 && tapTrick==1) {
        Tab1.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, MainActivity.this);
    }else if (tapTrick!=0 && tapTrick==2){
        //Tab2.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, MainActivity.this);
    }
}
```

Fragment 1

```
MainActivity.tapTrick=1; // onCreateView  or onClick (load images/files)

 public static void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent, Context context) {
 }
```

Fragment 2

```
MainActivity.tapTrick=2;
 public static void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent, Context context) {
 }
```

Fragment x

```
MainActivity.tapTrick=x;
 public static void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent, Context context) {
 }
```