# Zxing QR scanner onActivityResult not called in fragment

Tags: android, zxing

I'm using [zxing android](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded) to san QR code.

To initialise scan object in HomeFragment in onCreateView:

```
//intializing scan object
//qrScan = new IntentIntegrator(this.getActivity()); // this is for activity
qrScan = IntentIntegrator.forSupportFragment(this); // this is for fragment
```

To get the scanner result:

```
// Get the results:
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
if(result != null) {
    if(result.getContents() == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Scanned: " + result.getContents(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
} else {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

However, I'm getting:

> error: onActivityResult(int,int,Intent) in HomeFragment cannot
>   override onActivityResult(int,int,Intent) in Fragment attempting to
>   assign weaker access privileges; was public

After changing it from "protected" to public, onActivityResult was not called in HomeFragment.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20013213/zxing-onactivityresult-not-called-in-fragment-only-in-activity

Comment: Have you overridden `onActivityResult()` in the hosting `Activity`? If so, are you calling the `super` method there?

Comment: Thanks Mike M. I've missed out calling the super method in the Activity. Able to capture the QR code content. However it's rather hard for me to scan a simple QR code ("hello world android" text), is there any ways to improve the speed of capturing? I've added "android:hardwareAccelerated="true"" in AndroidManifest.xml but it's still slow.

Comment: Sorry, but that's a separate question. I've not used ZXing. I just checked your question for the `Fragment` result issue.

Comment: Thanks @MikeM. Found out it's cause by the debugger. Running smoothly now

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = IntentIntegrator.forSupportFragment(YourFragmentClass.this);
scanIntegrator.setPrompt("Scan");
scanIntegrator.setBeepEnabled(true);
scanIntegrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(true);
scanIntegrator.initiateScan();
```

Then in `onActivityResult`

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (scanningResult != null) {
        if (scanningResult.getContents() != null) {
            scanContent = scanningResult.getContents().toString();
            scanFormat = scanningResult.getFormatName().toString();
        }

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), scanContent + "   type:" + scanFormat, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        textView.setText(scanContent + "    type:" + scanFormat);

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Nothing scanned", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

You can check [this](https://github.com/sshuvro58/BarCodeScanner) repo